# C# FileStream read set encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, filestream

There might be something obvious I'm missing here, but I can't seem to set the encoding on my FileStream read. Here's the code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (fs)
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];
                fs.Seek(chunk, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, chunk);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    ProcessChunk(buffer, bytesRead, database, id);
                    bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, chunk);
                }

            }
            fs.Close();
```

Where ProcessChunk saves the read values to objects which are then serialized to XML, but the characters read appear wrong. The encoding needs to be 1250. I haven't seen an option to add the encoding to the FileStream. What am I missing here?

Comment: try to use ```StreamWriter``` instead of ```FileStream```

Comment: Since you're reading *bytes*, there is no encoding. If those bytes make up text, it is the process of converting those bytes into text that requires an encoder. There is no trace of text processing in your code or question (other than "where do I specify encoder"), so the question is: Do you *need* an encoder?

Comment: The characters are mangled by `ProcessChunk` whose code is missing. A `FileStream` only returns bytes

Comment: Please post the code for `ProcessChunk`. How does it convert bytes to text? You can avoid the problem if you use the `1250` encoding, either in a StreamReader or with `Encoding.GetString`. You can get it with `Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)`

Answer (score 7):

Rather than FileStream, use StreamReader. It has several [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) which allow you to specify the Encoding. For example:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
```

Since you require encoding 1250, this can be done with:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
```

I would also suggest writing it as:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader ...etc)
```

rather than declaring the variable outside the using; and you don't need to do the Close outside the using, since [the Dispose will handle that](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,b5fe1efcec14de32).

Comment: How would I specify the chunk size using Streamreader? I need it to start at the specified start point in the file and read chunks of defined size one at a time, that's why I use FileStream.

Comment: There is an equivalent 'Read' method on StreamReader https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx ; it's just that now the Encoding is resolved, you have "char"s instead of "byte"s.

Comment: @Flopn you haven't posted the code for `ProcessChunk`. *That's* what's mangling the code. For people to tell you how to use a `StreamReader` with it they need to know what it does

Comment: @Richardissimo `Encoding.ASCII` is the 7-bit US ASCII codepage. This will mangle the characters just like the current code does - the 7-bit range is the same in almost all codepages, it's the values >127 that differ and get mangled

Comment: @Richardissimo and *reproduces the original bug*. Use the correct encoding instead. `Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use both FileStream and FileReader :

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
    {                                        
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            ProcessLine(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: The question asked for 1250, not 1250

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think everyone is capable of adapting code for such a simple thing ? ;-) 1252 is the Encoding set for Windows, so very common.

Comment: Its' even easier to fix the answer to match the question, making it a better match

Comment: Sorry I upvoted prematurely then. It's not a joke either, as 1252 is **not** the encoding set of Windows. It's the encoding used in certain Western European languages. Using it with Central or Eastern Europe text will mangle it, which is *precisely* what the OP's problem is. 1250 is the encoding used in Eastern Europe

Comment: Which means, right now neither answer solves the original problem (although the other answer manages to lose data too).

Comment: It is just what i need, Thank.