# Detecting special character in C# and replacing it with normal ASCII one

Tags: c#, unicode

I am reading file in C# that sometime contain special characters. As you can see in the screenshot given below, there is word `Zürich` but instead of `ü` it is showing some special character.

Is it possible to detect what that special character is and replace it with equivalent English character for e.g. in this case replacing it with `u`?

[image]

Comment: C# doesn't use ASCII, all strings are Unicode, (UTF-16 specifically). There are no special characters in Unicode. What you show is an attempt to display text using the wrong culture or codepage. Whatever displays that text either has a bug or is misconfigured

Comment: In fact, this very question is proof that there's absolutely no problem - Stack Overflow is a .NET application storing questions in `nvarchar` fields in SQL Server. That's why I can type `Zürich` and `Αυτό Εδώ` in the same comment without extra encoding or contacting SO admins

Comment: Where does this screenshot come from? Is that a screenshot of your application? Of the source file? Or another file you exported after processing the original? There may be no problem with your code, only the application that tries to display the text. Or you may be exporting the string using the wrong ASCII codepage instead of UTF8. We can't guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect what that special character is

Yes, but also no. You have to *know* in which encoding the file is written to get it right. The screenshot looks like Notepad++ (Scintilla), and Notepad++ has an encoding menu. Switch encodings until the characters look good.

You cannot reasonably do this through code. Sure, you can guess and do stuff like character frequency analysis, but an `ü` is stored as a certain number (code point, byte value(s)), and this number represents an `ü` in one or more code pages (encodings).

Obligatory: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) (it's 20 years old already!).

So if you know that the file is saved with a certain encoding (and it does *not* seem to be UTF-8, Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1), then read it with the given encoding: [C# FileStream read set encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791109/c-sharp-filestream-read-set-encoding).

If, on the other hand, the file actually contains [`□` ("'WHITE SQUARE' (U+25A1)", "may be used to represent a missing ideograph")](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm), then the original information (the code point of `ü`) is lost.

**tl;dr**: guess the encoding using your text editor's functionalities, or look (using a hex editor) what the numeric value of the character is, then find the appropriate encoding.

Comment: Yeah, I have opened this file in Notepad++ and tried many different encodings but no luck. Looks like this is `White Square (U+25A1)` so the information is lost.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the character by mouse (right click then select copy option) and use this code :

```
string text = <your text>;
string mainChar = <copied character>;
string altChar = "u";
text.Replace(mainChar, altChar);
```